# Get count of all unique rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame -

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=2,size=(5,3)),
...                       columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> data
   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  1  0  1
2  1  0  1
3  0  1  1
4  1  1  0
```

Now I use this to get the count of rows only for column A

```
>>> data.ix[:, 'A'].value_counts()
1    3
0    2
dtype: int64
```

What is the most efficient way to get the count of rows for column A and B i.e something like the following output -

```
0    0    0
0    1    2
1    0    2
1    1    1
```

And then finally how can I convert it into a numpy array such as -

```
array([[0, 2],
       [2, 1]])
```

Please give a solution that is also consistent with

```
>>>> data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=2,size=(5,2)),
...                       columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Comment: You can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as works this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You  can use groupby [size](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and then [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
In [11]: data.groupby(["A","B"]).size()
Out[11]:
A  B
0  1    2
1  0    2
   1    1
dtype: int64

In [12]: data.groupby(["A","B"]).size().unstack("B")
Out[12]:
B   0  1
A
0 NaN  2
1   2  1

In [13]: data.groupby(["A","B"]).size().unstack("B").fillna(0)
Out[13]:
B  0  1
A
0  0  2
1  2  1
```

**However** whenever you do a groupby followed by an unstack you should think: [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
In [21]: data.pivot_table(index="A", columns="B", aggfunc="count", fill_value=0)
Out[21]:
   C
B  0  1
A
0  0  2
1  2  1
```

*This will be the most efficient solution as well as being the most direct.*

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on A and B columns and then do [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) on the result. But with that you'll get only values which you have in your original dataframe. In your case you won't have `0 0` counts. After that you could call [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) method to get `numpy` array:

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  1  0  1
2  1  0  1
3  0  1  1
4  1  1  0

In [56]: df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).count()
Out[56]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  1  0  2
2  1  1  1

In [57]: df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).count().C.values
Out[57]: array([2, 2, 1])
```

Then you could use [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method of numpy array

For dataframe with all values:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  0  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  0  1
3  1  1  0
4  0  1  1
5  0  0  1
6  1  1  1
7  0  0  1
8  0  1  0
9  1  1  0

In [73]: df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).count()
Out[73]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  0  2
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  2
3  1  1  4


In [75]: df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).count().C.values.reshape(2,2)
Out[75]: 
array([[2, 2],
       [2, 4]])
```

Comment: But I cannot always ensure that all the rows will be present. I must acoount this case too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of your data is binary, you can just sum the columns.  To be safe, you then use `count` to get the total of all non null values in the column (the difference between this count and the previous sum is the number of zeros).

```
s = data[['A', 'B']].sum().values
>>> np.matrix([s, data[['A', 'B']].count().values - s])
matrix([[3, 3],
        [2, 2]]
```

If you are sure that there are no null values, you can save some computational time by just taking the number of rows from the first shape parameter.

```
>>> np.matrix([s, data.shape[0] - s])
matrix([[3, 3],
        [2, 2]]
```