# Python: how to count number of couple values repeated in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a dataframe `df`. Composed by `2` columns that denote the coordinates of a Matrix `M`. I defined the Matrix `M` as

```
s = [5, 5]
M = np.zeros((s[1], s[0]))
```

Now I want to add to count how times the same cell is called in the dataframe

```
df

       x      y  
0      1      4      
1      0      2      
3      3      1     
4      4      2     
5      4      2     
4      2      0
```

What I am doing is the following:

```
for i in df.index:
    M[df['x'][i]][df['y'][i]] += 1
```

I would like to do it in a more elegant way maybe grouping the pandas dataframe.

The output should generate a dataframe `df1` that count the number of times a couple `xy` is repeated, so:

df1

```
       x      y  count  
0      1      4    1  
1      0      2    1  
3      3      1    1 
4      4      2    2 
5      2      0    1
```

and the matrix `M`

```
M

array([[ 0.,   0.,  1.0,  0.,   0.],
       [ 0.,   0.,  0.,   1.0,  0.],
       [ 1.0,  0.,  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 0.,   1.,  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 0.,   0.,  2.,   0.,   0.]])
```

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the content. Please fix.

Comment: Can you also add your desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get count of all unique rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255882/get-count-of-all-unique-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this and reindex axis to cover missing values:

```
M = (df.groupby(['x','y'])['x']
       .count()
       .unstack()
       .reindex(index=np.arange(df.x.max()+1),
                columns=np.arange(df.y.max()+1))
       .fillna(0)
       .values)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  2.  0.  0.]]
```